# Does a GPS need a sim card?

Tags: gps

I am trying to use a NEO-6M GPS to datalog my current position on a Micro SD card with the help of an Arduino Pro Mini. It doesn't transmit anything. So do I need a SIM card?

> Caution:
>
> 1. The GPS tracker must be worked with a SIM card which may cost data and SMS fee.
> 2. No annual authorization fee for the first year. The coming annual fee details, please visit our company website.

Comment: There is nothing in this question relating to the Arduino. I suggest posting on the Electronics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For use as a GPS device, the NEO-6M doesn't need a SIM card.  For use as part of a tracker that sends SMS / GSM messages, ie, that uses the cell telephone system to send messages, you need a SIM card.  The SIM card is used to authenticate your system to the phone system.

See examples at "[arduino gps and sms where are you arduino](https://bigdanzblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/arduino-gps-and-sms-where-are-you-arny-the-arduino/)" (bigdanzblog.wordpress.com) and "[vehicle tracking system using arduino gps and gsm](http://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/vehicle-tracking-system-using-arduino-gps-and-gsm)" at circuitdigest.com.